# GPIO status after python code is closed

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, output

I intend to write a python script to change the status of GPIO pins. The code will receive arguments through sys.argv, change the state of some GPIO pins, and close afterward.

My question is: Do the state of GPIO pins (input/output) and their values (low/high) reset to the default state after the python script ends, or will their state persist until the next time the script runs and changes them again?

Comment: Upvoting and choosing an answer is the way to show your appreciation on this site.

Comment: I have the same question,  but I am using the gpiozero module.  But same problem/issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using RPi.GPIO and run `.cleanup()` at the end of your script, it will return the channel(s) back to inputs with no pull up/down.  Otherwise, they will remain in the state you left them.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/ for details.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This may be the same issue with gpiozero, but it perhaps does the cleanup by default.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the module you are using and if you have changed the GPIO state using the module (rather than indirectly by calling a shell program to change the state).

My pigpio leaves the GPIO in the last set state.

I'm not sure about wiringPi (Python).

RPi.GPIO and RPIO.GPIO both have a cleanup function.  If that is called then any GPIO you have changed with RPi or RPIO functions will be set as inputs with no (resistor) pulls.

Answer (score 2):

Status (input/output direction and value) will stay as set until they are changed again - unless your script explicitly messes with them (the other answers got that covered).